# django: 'python manage.py migrate' taking hours (and other weird behavior)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I made some changes to one of my tables in models.py and tried migrating it with 'python manage.py migrate,' and it's taking hours. I only changed the names of three field  (column) names, and it's been running for over 2 hours now. It ran smoothly (I think) in a matter of minutes when I created the table earlier this morning. Start of season is the model where changes were made.

Here is what from models.py looks like now:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels
# from django.contrib.gis import admin

# Create your models here.

class Location(models.Model): # table name automatically chirps_location
    locationID = models.IntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    lon = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    geom = gismodels.PointField(null=True)
    objects = gismodels.GeoManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"LocationID: " + unicode(self.locationID)

# admin.site.unregister(Location)
# admin.site.register(Location, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)


class Rainfall(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pentad_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)        
    pentad_val = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['location', 'year', 'pentad_num']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"LocationID: " + unicode(self.location.locationID) + u" Year: " + unicode(self.year) + u" Pentad: " + unicode(self.pentad_num)


class Start_of_Season(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    crop = models.CharField(default='', max_length=40)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    first_rain = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    onset_rain = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_season = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['location', 'crop', 'year']    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"LocationID: " + unicode(self.location.locationID) + u" Year: " + unicode(self.year) + u" Start of Season pentad: " + unicode(self.start_season)
```

There was also some weird behavior that I couldn't explain going on before this, so I'll give a brief rundown of all of that too in case it's all related.

At first, my Start_of_Season class looked like this (notice the only difference is the names of the last 3 fields):

```
class Start_of_Season(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    crop = models.CharField(default='', max_length=40)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    first_rain_pentad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    onset_rain_pentad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_season_pentad = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['location', 'crop', 'year']    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"LocationID: " + unicode(self.location.locationID) + u" Year: " + unicode(self.year) + u" Start of Season pentad: " + unicode(self.start_season)
```

Migrating it with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

appeared to run smoothly.

But when I ran a python script (excerpt) to add rows to this newly created Start_of_Season table:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "access.settings")
from chirps.models import Location, Rainfall, Start_of_Season
django.setup()

try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        for loc in Location.objects.all():
            locID = loc.locationID
            for yr in range(1981, 2014):
                # some computations to find: c1, c2, c3
                start_of_season = Start_of_Season()
                start_of_season.location = Location.objects.get(locationID = locID)
                start_of_season.crop = 'millet'
                start_of_season.year = yr
                start_of_season.first_rain_pentad = c1
                start_of_season.onset_rain_pentad = c2
                start_of_season.start_season_pentad = c3
                start_of_season.save()
```

At first, the rows were never added to the database (according to psql at least). Then I got the error "start_of_season has no attribute start_season" which is weird because I never tried to access that attribute in my script, only "start_of_season.start_season_pentad"

So then I thought, okay, I'll change the names of the fields so that start_of_season *does* have that attribute. And that's when I edited models.py to look like the excerpt at the top of the post.

After updating updating models.py,

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

ran with no errors:

```
(access_mw)mwooten@ip-10-159-67-226:~/dev/access$ python manage.py makemigrations
Did you rename start_of_season.first_rain_pentad to start_of_season.first_rain (a IntegerField)? [y/N] y
Did you rename start_of_season.onset_rain_pentad to start_of_season.onset_rain (a IntegerField)? [y/N] y
Did you rename start_of_season.start_season_pentad to start_of_season.start_season (a IntegerField)? [y/N] y
Migrations for 'chirps':
  0010_auto_20150901_1454.py:
    - Rename field first_rain_pentad on start_of_season to first_rain
    - Rename field onset_rain_pentad on start_of_season to onset_rain
    - Rename field start_season_pentad on start_of_season to start_season
```

, but:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

has been stuck here for hours:

```
(access_mw)mwooten@ip-10-159-67-226:~/dev/access$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, gis, djgeojson, messages, leaflet
  Apply all migrations: admin, chirps, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying chirps.0010_auto_20150901_1454...
```

I don't see why this should take so long, seeing as how creating the actual table didn't. I'm also not sure why I was getting the other errors. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: How much data is in the tables that are being changed? You should also post the migration that's taking a long time.

Comment: @schillingt According to psql , there were 0 rows in the table that was being changed. I did "SELECT * FROM chirps_start_of_season LIMIT 5;" after I created the table and tried adding rows, and it returned the field names, and "0 rows," which was problem #1. And it's also why I'm so confused as to why the migration is taking this long. That was last I checked--now that the migration is running, I can't look at the table in psql. Also, I'm new to django. How do I "post the migration"? Thanks!!

Comment: You have another sql client that's reading the table that's being migrated. Close all sql clients, django shells and try again

Comment: @e4c5 I realize this was a long time ago but if you can put this comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

More often than not this is because there is another SQL client or django server or shell reading/writing to the table that you are trying to modify.

An SQL command that changes a schema cannot be successfully executed while a table is being accessed. Ideally an error message should pop up but what usually happens is that the command just waits for the others to finish.

Once you close all your open shells, and sql clients, the schema change can happen. In the worst case, you might need to temporarily take the site offline too.

Comment: This was indeed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: glad to have helped

Comment: Same, my jupyter notebook had a postgresql conn and was holding back the migration

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't even start! I used docker-compose to run my project and my Dockerfile contained `RUN python manage.py migrate`. Turned out that I put debugpy code in manage.py and let it wait for the debugger using wait_for_client ***without*** pressing debug button in vscode, which took forever.

As per debugpy documentation ([Waiting for the client to attach](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy#waiting-for-the-client-to-attach))

> Use the `debugpy.wait_for_client()` function to block program execution until the client is attached.

Here what I was trying to do: [How to debug Django in VSCode with autoreload turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944426/8963778)